# Shorten 3 lines of code creating an object with a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make these three lines

```
this.door = create("img");
this.door.src = "img/door.png";
this.door.style.position = "absolute";
```

be easily repeated with one line like this, using a function

```
this.door = putimg("img/door.png");
```

since the only thing changing when I rewrite the lines for different elements is the `.src =` and original name of the object `this.door`.

I can't get it to work. I think this is a rather easy question. Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: What's `create` supposed to return?

Comment: oh I just have create(x); returning document.createElement(x);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to be the problem here?

```
function putimg(src) {
   var obj = create("img");
   obj.src = src;
   obj.style.position = "absolute";
   return obj;
}
```

Comment: Oh geez thank you! I had tried something similar but you have it right

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery you cann create a function like this:

```
function putimg(link){
    return $('<img>').attr('src',link).css('position','absolute');
};
```

The same thing can be done without jQuery but the code will be longer.

Comment: Oh nice, I have been using some jquery so I'll keep that in mind. Thank you

Comment: @Paulo: considering the length of jQuery library that needs to be included yes, I agree. But anyway, it's more convenient for programmer, isn't it. Thanks for voting up.

Comment: @chuepukha That depends. Although jQuery really gives a boot in productivity when banging out javascript code, it's not only good, but I think that is imperative, to a good developer to know how to do things without the need of a library. Because I have seen my share of people who have no clue of what's going on under the hood and get lost real fast with the slightest hickup of a library or a behavior of a browser...

Answer (score 0):

```
function createAbsoluteImg(src) {
    var result = create("img");
    result.src = src;
    result.style.position = "absolute";
    return result;
}

this.door = createAbsoluteImg("img/door.png");
this.window = createAbsoluteImg("img/window.png");
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems so obvious now